# Connect Sys as Sysdba : Insufficient privileges

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to connect to an Oracle database using SQL Developper as Sys DBA but I'm receiving the error : ORA 1031 : Insufficient Privileges.

I'm sure the password is correct because I'm able to connect to the same database using SQLPlus :

[image]

[image]

Does anyone know how to solve that please ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change role to be sysdba instead of default in sqldeveloper

Comment: Which means ? How you do that ?

Comment: after felling connection info name and host etc.
change type of connection role  to sysdba  instead of default in sql developer connection widow

Comment: c'est le Menu contextuel **rôle**

Answer (score 0):

Check if the parameter [REMOTE_LOGIN_PASSWORDFILE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/initparams198.htm#REFRN10184) is set to **exclusive**. This is necessary to login `AS SYSDBA` from SQL developer :

```
SQL> show parameter remote_login_passwordfile
```

To change it :

```
SQL> ALTER SYSTEM SET REMOTE_LOGIN_PASSWORDFILE=EXCLUSIVE SCOPE=SPFILE;
```

Comment: I tried the command **ALTER SYSTEM SET REMOTE_LOGIN_PASSWORDFILE=EXCLUSIVE SCOPE=SPFILE;** but it's not working. Still the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

Role(par defaut) - role(sysdba) or sysoper